# Absolute URLs instead of relative

Tags: 8, entities

I have a problem with <s>entity</s> URLs in D8. All of them are absolute instead of relative, which causes various problems. For example,link URLs to edit content on `/admin/content` look like this:

`http://example.local/node/693/edit?destination=http%3A//example.local/admin/content`

instead of

`/node/693/edit?destination=/admin/content`

- It's not theme-related issue
- I checked various custom classes implementing `OutboundRouteProcessorInterface` and it seems, that none of them should affect this

What could be the cause, then?

EDIT: It's the same with all Drupal-generated links.

BTW. The issue can be seen by executing

```
use Drupal\Core\Link;
$link = Link::createFromRoute('This is a link', 'entity.node.canonical', ['node' => 1])->toString();
print_r($link);
```

It should result in relative URL, in my case it's absolute one.

Comment: maybe htaccess? or something with render cache.

Comment: @IvanJaros Thanks, but it doesn't seem to be caused by server misconfiguration, because it's happening in different environments. Regarding render cache, do you have some related resource to share? Thanks

Comment: check the custom code base for use of setAbsolute() method on the Url object and of course, try one of the default themes.

Comment: @IvanJaros Thanks, that method is used only in a completely unrelated way. Also, it's not a theme issue, as I described in the issue.

Comment: check settings.php for some weird logic or proxy settings. also try disabling js

Comment: Just to double check a simple thing.. you are seeing the host on the href when you inspect the code right?  Not just the browser URL when you mouse over...  Just checking.  If it is in the URL, I wonder if it is a strange config setting for the base_url.  Maybe in the settings.php file?

Comment: @CGMonroe Of course, all this is checked in code inspector.

Comment: @IvanJaros Double-checked `settings.php` and `settings.local.php`. Nothing suspectible. Disabling JS didn't help.

Comment: Then it has to be some weird contrib module if it is behaving the same on different environments(ie. it is not apache/nginx issue). Try uninstalling one module at a time and see if any of them is the cause.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, it was caused by

```
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$config['language.negotiation']['url']['domains']['cs'] = $host;
```

in my `settings.php` file. Thanks all!